# Which is the correct form for a C++-CLI copy constructor?

Tags: c++-cli, copy-constructor

I have some code like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(MyClass^ objToCopyFrom);
```

Which is producing an error:

> 'type' : ref class does not have a user-defined copy constructor

When I look up [the error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173592.aspx), it suggests my code should look like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(MyClass% objToCopyFrom);
```

My question is therefore, which version is correct or are they both correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only your second version is correct:

```
MyClass::MyClass(MyClass% objToCopyFrom);
```

or its variant:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass% objToCopyFrom);
```

`MyClass%` is a so-called [Tracking Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a.aspx) which is the conceptual equivalence of a reference in native C++, only for CLR types.

While [copy constructors in native C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) can have a number of different signatures, what they all have in common is that the *other* object that's being copied is passed in as a *reference*. C++/CLI stays close to that principle, but uses its own type of object references, a tracking reference.

Comment: Sounds right although I've read that CLI ignores the `const` you mention.